# Use Java to Crawl and download entire website overriding the HttpsURLConnection

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, crawler4j, websphinx

I am looking to crawl the entire website and save it locally offline. It should have 2 parts:

1. Authentication

This needs to be implemented using Java and I need to override HttpsURLConnection logic to add couple lines of authentication (Hadoop) in order to fetch the url response (keytabs). Something like below:

```
     AuthenticatedURL.Token token = new AuthenticatedURL.Token();

    URL ur = new URL(url);
    //HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(new     HostnameVerifierSSL());
    HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) new AuthenticatedURL().openConnection(ur, token);
```

2. Once all the links go through the above authentication, we need to crawl the entre website until depth =3 and save it locally offline as a zip.

Let me know possible solutions.

Comment: Are you offering a job ? Trying to get your work done ?

Comment: Lol. Nope. Just trying to solve a problem :)